# split string between last occurrence of of a to z of character in c #

Tags: c#, split

I have  one string for example "2244cc101" and I want to split this string into "2244cc" and "101" So I just need to split the string where  last any character between a to z or A to Z without for loop
take another example where s224s01  that should split like "s224s" and "01".

Comment: what have  u tried so far?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

For both languages, you need to use regexp.
I can show how to do this with js and try to explain in the comments:

```js
const firstString = "2244cc101";
const secString = "s224s01";
const pattern = /\d{2,3}$/; // 2 or 3 last numbers. $ - mean the end of string

function checkString(string) {
   const lastNumbers = string.match(pattern); // return array with the last 2 or 3 numbers in the end of the string;
   console.log("last numbers in the string: " + lastNumbers);
      
   const indexOfLastNubmers = lastNumbers.index; //find the index of the last numbers in the string
   console.log("Index for split: "+indexOfLastNubmers);
      
   if (!indexOfLastNubmers) { // check does the string have 2 or 3 numbers in the end. If no, return null.
      return null;
   }
      
   const firstPartOfString = string.slice(0, indexOfLastNubmers); // return the first part of string without last numbers
      
   return new Array(firstPartOfString, lastNumbers[0]);
      
};

let result = checkString(firstString);
console.log("Result of checking the first string: " + result);

result = checkString(secString);
console.log("Result of checking the second string: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be complicated, but try this

```js
let string = "2244cc101"
let string2 = "s224s01"

function splitStr(string) {
  let arr = string.split('');
  for (let j = arr.length; j--;) {
    if (arr[j].match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
      let last = arr[j]
      return [string.slice(0, string.lastIndexOf(last) + 1), string.slice(string.lastIndexOf(last) + 1)];
    }
  }
}

console.log(splitStr(string))
console.log(splitStr(string2))
```